# VBA macro hidden glitch

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I ve got following problem. When I run code below, I am getting the correct result up to 114 of rows created by this macro, and after that it is stoped. I got error saying "Application-defined or object-defined error" and it point to this row of code.

```
Range("O" & (i + 1)) = reportDate((i + 5) Mod 6)
```

Could anyone help me to find reason of this. Here is the code. Thx for any help.

```
Sub hmm()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim zakres As Integer
Dim rfiNumber(5) As String
Dim reportDate(5) As Date
Dim reportName(5) As String
Dim formName(5) As String
Dim rest(7) As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim item As String
Dim l As Integer

Workbooks("EAP_ZESTAWIENIE_pits+covers.xls").Activate
Worksheets("COVER").Select

zakres = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("I:I"))

formName(0) = "MDT.CV.CDQ.0204"
formName(1) = "MDT.CV.CDQ.0205"
formName(2) = "MDT.CV.CDQ.0207"
formName(3) = "MDT.CV.CDQ.0801"
formName(4) = "MDT.CV.CDQ.0802"
formName(5) = "MDT.CV.CDQ.0803"

rest(0) = "CV"
rest(1) = "'08"
rest(2) = "'00"
rest(3) = "'0005"
rest(4) = "F17162"
rest(5) = "S001"
rest(6) = "PEK001"
rest(7) = "CV-0800"

j = 1

For i = 1 To (zakres - 2) * 3

If (((i + 6) Mod 6) = 1) Then

Worksheets("COVER").Select

item = Range("A" & (2 * j + 1))
itemDescription = Range("S" & (2 * j + 1))

rfiNumber(0) = Range("B" & (2 * j + 1))
rfiNumber(1) = Range("C" & (2 * j + 1))
rfiNumber(2) = " "
rfiNumber(3) = " "
rfiNumber(4) = Range("K" & (2 * j + 1))
rfiNumber(5) = Range("M" & (2 * j + 1))

reportDate(0) = Range("E" & (2 * j + 1))
reportDate(1) = Range("E" & (2 * j + 1))
reportDate(2) = Range("E" & (2 * j + 1))
reportDate(3) = Range("E" & (2 * j + 1))
reportDate(4) = Range("L" & (2 * j + 2))
reportDate(5) = Range("N" & (2 * j + 2))

reportName(0) = Range("F" & (2 * j + 1))
reportName(1) = Range("G" & (2 * j + 1))
reportName(2) = Range("H" & (2 * j + 1))
reportName(3) = Range("J" & (2 * j + 1))
reportName(4) = Range("L" & (2 * j + 1))
reportName(5) = Range("N" & (2 * j + 1))

j = j + 1

End If

Worksheets("import").Select

Range("A" & (i + 1)) = rest(4)
Range("B" & (i + 1)) = rest(5)
Range("C" & (i + 1)) = item
Range("D" & (i + 1)) = itemDescription
Range("F" & (i + 1)) = rest(6)
Range("G" & (i + 1)) = rest(7)
Range("H" & (i + 1)) = rest(0)
Range("I" & (i + 1)) = rest(1)
Range("J" & (i + 1)) = rest(2)
Range("K" & (i + 1)) = "'000" & ((i + 5) Mod 6) + 1
Range("L" & (i + 1)) = formName((i + 5) Mod 6)
Range("M" & (i + 1)) = rfiNumber((i + 5) Mod 6)
Range("N" & (i + 1)) = "CertCode" & "CV08000" & (((i + 5) Mod 6) + 1) & reportName((i + 5) Mod 6)
Range("O" & (i + 1)) = reportDate((i + 5) Mod 6)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `reportDate((i + 5) Mod 6)` at the time of error?

Comment: He is not giving any data. He break just before.

Comment: Do you know how to debug using 'F8'

Comment: or if you can check what is the value of `i` and `j` at that moment

Comment: Try `Range("O" & (i + 1)).Value` instead of just `Range("O" & (i + 1))`?

Comment: Yes I know, I used it and everything is going good up to this moment, I dont know what is there in that time.

Comment: Can you upload your file to any free file sharing website and share the link here?

Comment: loop is not exceded i=112, j=2

Comment: adding value aint change a thing

Comment: `loop is not exceded i=112, j=2 ` Could you check what is the value of cell `E5` Does the cell have a formula error?

Comment: http://uplodzik.pl/download.php?uid=1JXHVGWE here is the link

Comment: Hmm, In that case are you sure that the value of i is `112` and j is `2`? Also the file you uploaded has only one sheet...

Comment: it was supposed to be j=20 sry

Comment: there is more sheets but data are extracted from this one and the destination sheet is just empty one

Comment: Ok do this.. replace your code with my code. DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN MY CODE :) Copy it as you see it in this text file and replace with with your code. Also take a backup of your code. http://wikisend.com/download/178942/Codetest.txt Now tell me what messagebox do you get?

Comment: the thing is i am still at work at got here websense blocade on this one, maybe you can use the one i used though it is in polish

Comment: http://uplodzik.pl/download.php?uid=1DQR6NNF

Comment: ehh upload was possibile but not download, let me reach home(90 min )and I will give you feedback on this one

Answer (score 0):

In your spreadsheet, **L40** has a date value that can be interpreted internally as a date, but when placed on the spreadsheet, it cannot be recognized as a dateserial that is used for dates on a spreadsheet.

in VBA:
Date variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers that represent dates ranging from **1 January 100** to **31 December 9999** and times from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59.

on Spreadsheet, the date must be between January 1, 1900 and December 31, 9999.

As L40 contains `08/07/213`, this is valid for vba, but not for excel.

Also, I would use `Option Explicit` - I had to define 2 variables to get the code to run in my configuration:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim itemDescription As String
```

Comment: I was checking this data L40 but not enough carefully, didnt see missing '0'. Big thanks for pointing that out.